# sync custom events to default phone calendar in android

Tags: android

i have an application in which i need to sync the events that i get from an xml to the default calendar provided in the users phone.
for the above i have referred [this](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276) tutorial.But over here the first it is required to get the id and name of all the available calendars in the users phone... i don't know the id and name of the  default calendar in the users phone....which calendar should i use to put events in?

i am not putting the code here as the code is present in the link given.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know ahead of time.  There is no system setting for the default calendar.  You must account for this in your application by allowing the user to select the calendar or coming up with your own way of determining the "default".

Be careful not to rely on the persistence of any calendar because if they are Google calendars they will come and go with corresponding changes in the cloud.